# Running Capistrano tasks only for certain roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, roles, task

My project has a multi-step pipeline that includes some steps like Crawling, NLP, etc, but I'll just refer to them as Step1, Step2, etc.  Additionally I want to be able to deploy to different environments (dev, prod, etc).

I figure I'll use multistage component for Capistrano in order to deploy to the different environments (e.g. cap dev deploy vs cap prod deploy).

It also seems to make intuitive sense to use roles for each pipeline step.  However, each step runs fairly independently of the rest of the pipeline, so each step can be restarted/deployed independently of the other steps.  It doesn't seem like Capistrano explicitly supports running tasks only for a specific role.  What's a good way to do this?

Is the best way of doing this defining tasks specifically for each role?  What if there are some tasks common between roles?  Maybe helper methods is the answer there?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but when I want to do something just to a particular role, I use the capistrano shell. For example, let's say I want to deploy but only to my app servers, I might do the following:

```
cap production shell
cap>with app
cap>!deploy #or any other cap task you have
```

You can also scope by machine if you want. Again:

```
cap production shell
cap>on <machine name or ip>
cap>!deploy #or any other cap task you have
```

Hope it helps,

Scott

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a capistrano task from the command line, but only for a subset of defined roles, you can use the `ROLES` parameter.

The command below executes the task `category:task` only for role `was`:

```
cap ROLES=was category:task
```

The `ROLES` parameter is multivalued, so you can add more roles separated by a comma:

```
cap ROLES=was,db category:task
```

For more details, you can refer to the [invoke](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks#invoke) documentation

Answer (score 1):

Check this discussion [Creating a Capistrano task that performs different tasks based on role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754015/creating-a-capistrano-task-that-performs-different-tasks-based-on-role)

```
task :stop_memcached, :roles => :memcache do 
...
end
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.  For example, if I had a task like:
`
    task :clear_logs do
      run "rm -f /tmp/blah.log"
    end
`
as part of a deployment, I would want to run it on all my machines if I were deploying all the Steps in my pipeline.  But if I'm only deploying Step2 of the pipeline, I would only want to clear the logs on all the machines that have the role of Step2.

The problem with roles that I'm encountering is that they are good at specifying which machines to run tasks on, but you can't seem to specify whether to actually run them or not for a particular deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure at what version the feature was added, but cap will look in the ROLES environment variable to determine which roles to run so

```
$ ROLES=db cap deploy
```